# datarow by column name

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable, datarow

I am using this code:

```
Dim dr() As DataRow = datatable.Select("id='" & st)
For i = 0 To dr.GetUpperBound(0)
    result = dr(i)(2).ToString()
Next i
```

How do I get result by column name instead of `dr(i)(2)`? Because if I add a column to that data table in front, then I get the wrong data, I should use `dr(i)(3)`. So I want to overcome this without changing source code in the future. Something like `dr(i)("column_name").ToString()`

Comment: Indices are zero based in .NET.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exactly like you wrote it:

```
dr(i)("column_name").ToString()
```

MSDN reference:

- [DataRow.Item Property (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For strongly typed value of other types (for example, Integer, you could use `Field(Of T)` extension):

- [DataRowExtensions.Field(Of T) Method (DataRow, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In your case,

```
dr(i).Field(Of String)("column_name")
```